# Figures in opposite order than they're placed

Tags: floats, feynmp

I'm attempting to place two feynman diagrams using feynmp in the figure environment so they can have a caption and their numbering is the same as other figures. However doing so they come out in the opposite order that they're inserted, however the captions are in the right order.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{fmffile}{diagram}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(160,100)
\fmfleft{i1,i2} \fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
\fmf{fermion}{i2,v1,o2}
\fmfv{label=$g$,label.angle=90}{v1}
\fmfdot{v1}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\caption{ONE}
\label{fig:one}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{fmffile}{diagram}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(160,100)
\fmfleft{i1} \fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
\fmf{photon}{v1,o2}
\fmfv{label=$g$,label.angle=90}{v1}
\fmfdot{v1}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\caption{TWO}
\label{fig:two}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

With this the diagram with no photon is written first, with a caption "ONE", and the diagram with a photon is written second with a caption "TWO". However the output puts the diagram with a photon before the diagram without a photon, and it also gives the diagram with a photon the caption "ONE".

The expected ordering:[image: correct figure order]

The outputted ordering:[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has this problem in the future (or more realistically I have the problem again and forget what the solution was) the diagrams need to have a different name in `\begin{fmffile}{diagram}`, i.e. one can be `\begin{fmffile}{diagram1}` and the other `\begin{fmffile}{diagram2}`. I do not know why or what this argument does, but this solves it.